# Good sites for website background patterns

Tags: background, design-patterns, wiki

What sites do you guys use for background patterns? The best I found so far is http://www.noupe.com/design/80-stunning-background-patterns-for-your-websites.html

http://www.noupe.com/freebie/the-big-collection-of-free-design-textures.html

Just wondering what other sources you guys use. I think this should be community wiki but I am really new and don't know how that works :(

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon http://www.backgroundlabs.com/